# unable to download llama2 weights because of http error 416

Tags: nlp, llm

i am trying to download the weights for llama2 7b-chat but i always end up with "Connecting to download.llamameta.net (52.84.205.116:443)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable"
i have requested the url multiple times but this doesnt resolve the issue.

Comment: How are you downloading the llama 2 weights? Additionally, have you checked the [following github issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama/issues/760)?

Comment: i am downloading it by running the download.sh file and entering the url
i have checked the issue on github but it doesnt seem to have a solution that works.
Also i am installing on windows os is there anything i should look into regarding that?